# What property inside the form can I use to assign this index string ['size']value as a value of the property?

Tags: php

I have this database field that used as the form input value '. $variety['price']. ' I also have a '. $variety['size']. ' database field that carry the name of the product but I don't know what another form input property to use to assign this size database field as a value to the input form property?

I feel like I have run out of properties to carry more values to other values beside price to cart.php.

Thank you the script is as below.

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
foreach($product['varieties'] as $variety){ 
echo'<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '"  />';
}
</form>
```

Comment: I think you have to elaborate your question a little more, I don't really know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list()` does exactly that, yes.

Try something like this with you php script: 
 - Submit your form, to another script, say, carttest.php
 - Put this code in carttest.php.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

You will see what data structure you have to deal with. from there, you might be able to work it out. Also look at some information on how to handle arrays in html form.

Comment: what the list function will do here?

Comment: will it make $price and $size two independent variables?

Comment: excuse me I question you a lot but I don't understand how to receive it in the page script. you said I should put the name="price[id]" in the form or leave it is?

Comment: I solved that problem, but that was not the way I supposed to go about it. it did worked but now there is a query troubling me..